# Unable to pass a parameter to my function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following in a common.php file:

```
$debug = true;

function debug_to_screen(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                print("Debug Mode: " + $value); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

In my main file I then call this function with the following:

```
require("common.php");     

if(!isset($_COOKIE["qcore"])) 
{
    debug_to_screen("Cookie not found: ", var_dump($_COOKIE['qcore']));
}
```

However I'm receiving the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\QCORE\login.php
>   on line 8

This is one of the first time's I've tried making a function that can be passed multiple values, so I don't have the skill set to understand why this isn't working. Basically - I'd like to make a debug function that I can pass multiple values to, that is defined in my common file.

Comment: Why do you use `&` here? Any particular reason for that? Not even mention that: a) `debug_to_screen` accepts 1 parameter but you're passing 2. b) `debug_to_screen` accepts parameter to be an array, while you're passing a string. c) `var_dump` returns `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
debug_to_screen("Cookie not found: "...
```

You are passing to the function which is expecting the data to be passed by reference - meaning you are sending it the ACTUAL variable, not a copy of it.

You will need to make the array first, then pass i by reference to the function.

Something like this:

```
$array=$_COOKIE;
debug_to_screen($array);
```

In your function, you defined it as:

```
function debug_to_screen(&$array)
```

The extra `&` means the function is taking the ACTUAL variable, not a copy of it.

This will also not work:

```
function julie(&$bob)
{
// something..
}


julie(5);
```

This is because although the function can change the 5, it cannot be returned via the reference pass.

```
$var1=5;
julie($var1);
```

This would have worked perfectly well, as $var1 can be modified and the external code calling the function can use the changed variable.

Answer (score 2):

You function `function debug_to_screen(&$array)` accepting only one argument and however you are sending text as first argument and cookies as second argument.

So

replace

```
debug_to_screen("Cookie not found: ", var_dump($_COOKIE['qcore']));
```

to

```
debug_to_screen($_COOKIE['qcore']);
```

Comment: I don't think so? If I pass one parameter I receive an error like the following: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\junglegym\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\QCORE\login.php on line 86

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to pass by reference, and you're passing two arguments when only one is defined. You're also trying to `print` an array, var_dump prints not returns.

I think you need to look at the PHP docs for the functions you're using, there are a number of issues here.